# Question about open set and its boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have might the following question, could you please help me to check if my answer is correct?

Let $A=\{(x,y):x\ge 1\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$. Then

- Is $A$ bounded? Justify
- what is the boundary?
- prove $A$ is not open
- find the largest open subset of $A$.

My answer:

- $A$ is not bounded, but I don't know how to justify it...can I simply say that for any $(x,y)$  in $A$, we can always find $(2x,2y)$ also in $A$ so that $|(2x,2y)-(x,y)|>0$?
- I guess the boundary is $\{(x,y):x=1\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$?
- Suppose $A$ is open, then for any point $(x,y)$ in $A$, there is a open ball around $(x,y)$ lies entirely in $A$. However, pick $(0,0)$. Then $D_r((0,0))$ with $r<1$. Then $(r/2,r/2)$ is in this open ball but not in $A$, contradiction. Is this rigorous?
- My guess is the $\{(x,y):x> 1\}$

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: So $A$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, right ?

Comment: The question didnt specify, but I assume yes

Comment: What the definition of bounded.  Just apply it directly. For example if your text says. $S$ is bounded if there is an $M\in R$ so that for any $x,y\in S$ then $d(x,y)< M$. then point out that for any $M$ then $(1, M), (1,0)\in A$ and $d((1,M),(1,0))= |M| \ge M$ so there are can no such $M$.  And so on.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bounded?  No.  For any bound, $M > 1$, the point $(M+1,0) \in A$ and $|(M+1,0)| = M+1 > M$.

Boundary?  Agree with your answer.

A is not open?  $(0,0) \in A \cap \partial A$.

Alternatively, $A$ is the complement of the union of four open sets, $\{(x,y) : x < 0\} \cup \{(x,y) : -1 < x < 1, y > 0\} \cup \{(x,y) : -1 < x < 1, y < 0\} \cup \{(x,y) : 0 < x < 1\}  \text{,}$ which union is open.  Therefore, $A$ is the complement of an open set, hence is closed.

Largest open subset?  Agree with your answer.  Your answer is the interior of $A$, that is, $A \smallsetminus \partial A$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have heard people say that a set can be both open and closed?

Comment: @CapitalSparrow : In $\Bbb{R}$, both $\Bbb{R}$ and $\varnothing$ are open and are closed.  These examples is definitional (definition of [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Definition_via_open_sets)).  However, what I think you are getting at (without being at all clear) is "the complement of an open set is closed".  A very common definition of [closed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set) is "the complement of an open set".  It is a typical lemma when using a boundary-based (or limit point based) definition of closed set to show this is equivalent.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks!